# overriding a virtual method, but with a new signature: so custom model binder can be used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abstract-class

I've got an abstract class with a virtual function defined:

```
public abstract class ContentController
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index();
}
```

I've got a class that derives from the above base class:

```
public class CartController : ContentController
```

I need the CartController to be able to bind a cart with a custom model binder on its Index method. Something that would normally look like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(Cart cart)
```

If I just place the Index(Cart) function into the CartController class, I get this error:

```
The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'CartController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
ActionResult Index() on type CartController
ActionResult Index(Cart) on type CartController
```

The only solution I've come up with thus far is to rename my model binding function and redirect from the overriden Index method:

```
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("IndexWithCart");
    }

    public ActionResult IndexWithCart(Cart cart)
    {
        return View("Index", cart); 
    }
```

That works, but then my URL is /Cart/IndexWithCart. Is there any way to accomplish this and still have just the /Cart URL, without modifying the base class?

Comment: Nick - does this not then require a new view called IndexWithCart as well?? (i.e. given that the return value of ActionResult IndexWithCart() is purely View(cart))

Comment: I updated the above IndexWithCart method above with how I have it in my code (returning the Index view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah just setup your route to point to the IndexWithCart action when you have the /Cart URL:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "IndexWithCartRoute",
                "Cart",
                new { controller = "Cart", action = "IndexWithCart" }
            );
```

Comment: This was my gut feeling to do as well. It just feels to me like that's not really what route mapping is meant for. Know what I mean?

Comment: @Nick - See that is the beauty of route mapping. You can take a clean URI and map it to any sort of controller or action that you want.  If we didn't have mappings then we would have to follow the same convention all the time for URI's to map correctly to controllers or actions.  This way we can specify our URI anyway we want and have control over making sure it gets handled by the right action on the right controller.

Comment: Came back to this months later, and went this route (no pun intended). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about (for the base controller):

```
public abstract class ContentController<T> : Controller
{
    public abstract ActionResult Index(T item);
}
```

followed by (for the inherited controller):

```
// just for the example
public class Cart
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : ContentController<Cart>
{
    public override ActionResult Index(Cart item)
    {
        //var cart = new Cart {Foo = "this is my cart test"};
        //return View(cart);  
        return View(item); 
    }
}
```

might work.

**[edit]** - a second way may be to try (base class):

```
public abstract class ContentController<T> : Controller 
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    internal ActionResult Index(T item)
    {
        return View(item);
    }
}
```

and for the controller:

```
// just for the example
public class Cart
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : ContentController<Cart>
{
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        Cart cart = null; // new Cart { Foo = "this is my 1st cart test" };
        if (cart != null)
            return Index(cart);
        else
            return base.Index();
    }
}
```

i'm all thunked out now :)

Answer (score 0):

how about using **[HttpPost]** then
action 'Index' will not be ambiguous in your Base Controllor and child Controllor

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Cart cart)

```
{    

    return View(cart);    

}
```